# How to order posts from WordPress get_posts() function using date-formatted post titles

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a abit weird case where I have a list of custom posts which I need to order upon displaying them using the get_posts() WordPress function.

The post titles are basically dates which have the following format - dd-mm-yyyy
example;

```
18-11-2021
19-11-2021
etc...
```

Now, I need to order the posts but the typical `order_by` will not apply in my case because I don't wish to order by `date_modified/date posted` because the posts, when following this manner, are mixed up. For example.

I can post a new custom post like `18-11-2021` and then post tomorrow a post with title `18-10-2020` and the following day another post `12-12-2022`. This means using the date_posted/modified filter will not work.

I need to order using the titles as they are. But using `order_by => 'title'` still has the mixup. So I was wondering if there is another way I can probably adapt the `order_by => 'title'` to a something like a numeric format which follows some order.

Comment: You can't directly order by title, because your date format is not "sortable" - if it was `YYYY-MM-DD`, then this would work. AFAIK WordPress has no way of applying a callback function or something on the value first. So your options are to either sort the result in PHP afterwards (will only work smoothly, if you don't need any pagination), or to put your date in a proper sortable format into an extra custom field, so that you can sort by that one then.

Comment: So you are telling me if I convert the titles to yyyy-mm-dd order_by title works. That's simpler!

Comment: If your titles start with a date in that form (or consist only of that date), then this should work fine. This uses string comparison then, character-by-character, from left to right - so `2022-12-12` would be considered greater than `2021-11-18`.